# Show that eigen values of a matrix remain invariant under rotation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Show that eigen values of   a matrix remain invariant under rotation.
>
> HINT:Consider $QAQ^T$ where $Q^TQ=I$

**I am unable to answer this question.I don't know what is meant by rotation of a matrix.**

On using the hint I have shown that if $\lambda $ is an eigen value of $A$ corresponding to $v$ then $\lambda $ is an eigen vector of $QAQ^T$ corresponding to $Qv$.

But I don't understand how that solves the problem of rotation of matrices or what is meant by that.
Neither do I understand why should I find eigen values of $Q^TAQ$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the *rotation of a matrix*. It is the rotations of the 3-dimensional space;   and hence the corresponding changes in  co-ordinates are given by a matrix $Q$ satisfying $Q^TQ=I$.  So the original matrix $A$ gets transformed to  $QAQ^{-1}$. This matrix has the same eigenvalues as $A$ (in fact they have the same characteristic polynomials). However eigenvectors would be most of the times different.

Comment: Why does it get transferred to $QAQ^T$ ?Can you please explain

Comment: Matrices corresponding to rotations are *orthogonal*, that means their transposes are their inverses. IN 2-dimensional case the rotation of the axes by angle $\theta$  means $(1,0)$ goes to $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ and $(0,1)$ goes to $(-\sin\theta, \cos\theta)$. A $2\times2$  matrix  with  $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ and $(-\sin\theta, \cos\theta)$ as its rows (or columns) can be readily checked to be orthogonal.

Comment: No my problem is not that ;I am asking how to show that the resultant matrix will be $QAQ^T$

Comment: If $(v_1,v_2,\ldots,,v_n)$ is a new basis (as opposed to the standard basis consisting of columns of identity matrix) and if $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n$ are the co-ordinates of a vector in the new basis then its co-ordinates with respect to the standard basis  is the result of multiplication of the $n\times n$ matrix consisting of new basis vectors   (as columns) with the column vector $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. From this one can derive the matrix of a linear transformation after a change of basis as $QAQ^{-1}$ which becomes $QAQ^T$ in the orthogonal case.

Answer (score -1):

I have an observation to make regarding the last sentence in Vancinathan's response:

"However eigenvectors would be most of the times different"

This needs qualification. The eigenvectors, as coordinate independent vectors, also do not change. Only the components of eigenvectors change. As Learnmore has stated in his question if v is eigenvector of A then Qv is an eigenvector of QAQ^-1. But then Qv is actually the same vector v in a coordinate system rotated by Q just like QAQ^-1 is the same transformation as A but in the rotated coordinate system.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1696536)